# CMMotionManager is a global resource? What does this means?

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, core-motion

I am trying to initialize the CMMotionManager so start updates and create a reference attitude matrix, and then when i click a button trough the storyboard, i display a different screen (which is in a viewcontroller) and i want to use the reference attitude matrix and other readings from the motion manager but if I do a simple check to see if its ready it says it isnt (even thought it was ready on the previous screen).

So I was researching a little bit and i came across some standford notes that say it is a global resource so that it is ok to either use delegates or classes, that got me thinking.

If i use a delegate then technically the owner of the resource is doing the action for me right? so it doesnt really mean it is global.

What about classes? i tried implementing a MotionManager Class but i still didnt get any readings on the second screen... and i just didnt initialize it again on the new screen because i dont want to have multiple instances runing at the same time.

To solve my problem i also suppose i could initialize it once in the main one, save the attitude, pass it to the next one in a segue transition and just re initialize the motion manager so i only have 1 instance (or close old one on screen will dissapear).

But i do not want this because the user might click right away on the screen and the motion manager does take a little bit of time to initialize (or thats what i noticed).

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

**EDIT:**

Ok i tried the delegate method and i still cant read from the device manager in the second window. What comes to mind is that MAYBE when I am going to the second window xcode is automaticaly releasing my instance of Motion manager.... (CMMotionManager).

Anyone knows how to check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood you right. Then I suggest using a singleton design pattern encapsulating motion manager access in a specialised class. Some pseudo code:

MotionHandler.h

```
@interface MotionHandler {
    CMMotionManager* motionManager;

    + (MotionHandler*) getInstance;
}
```

MotionHandler.c:

```
@interface MotionHandler {

    static MotionHandler* instance;

    + (MotionHandler*) getInstance {
        if (instance == nil) {
            instance = [[self alloc] init];
        }
        return instance;
    }

    - (id)init {
        if ((self = [super init])) {
            motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
            // initialise CMMotionManager
        }
    }
}
```

So there is one instance of MotionHandler only which manages access to CMMotionManager. You can accesss your CMMotionManager instance from everywhere with `MotionHandler.getInstance.motionManager`.

If you need access to CoreMotion from several classes, I recommend total encapsulation of CMMotionManager access. That means make it @private and provide methods like getDeviceMotion, setReferenceAttitude, ...
This helps to avoid complications like starting it twice or access to CMDeviceMotion before start and makes it more convenient to debug.